# Optional binding succeeds if it shouldn't

Tags: ios, generics, swift

This is what I posted as a possible solution to [Traverse view controller hierarchy in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828147/traverse-view-controller-hierarchy-in-swift) (slightly modified):

```
extension UIViewController {

    func traverseAndFindClass<T where T : UIViewController>(T.Type) -> T? {
        var currentVC = self
        while let parentVC = currentVC.parentViewController {
            println("comparing \(parentVC) to \(T.description())")
            if let result = parentVC as? T { // (XXX)
                return result
            }
            currentVC = parentVC
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

The method should traverse up the parent view controller hierarchy and return the first
instance of the given class, or nil if none is found.

But it does not work, and I cannot figure out why. The optional binding
marked with `(XXX)` *always succeeds*, so that the first parent view controller is returned
even if it is not an instance of `T`.

This can easily be reproduced: Create a project from the "iOS Master-Detail Application"
template in Xcode 6 GM, and add the following code to `viewDidLoad()` of the
`MasterViewController` class:

```
if let vc = self.traverseAndFindClass(UICollectionViewController.self) {
    println("found: \(vc)")
} else {
    println("not found")
}
```

`self` is a `MasterViewController` (a subclass of `UITableViewController`), and its
parent view controller is a `UINavigationController`.
There is no `UICollectionViewController` in the parent view
controllers hierarchy, so I would expect that the method
returns `nil` and the output is "not found".

But this is what happens:

```
comparing <UINavigationController: 0x7fbc00c4de10> to UICollectionViewController
found: <UINavigationController: 0x7fbc00c4de10>
```

This is obviously wrong, because `UINavigationController` is not a subclass of
`UICollectionViewController`. Perhaps I made some stupid error, but I could not find it.

---

In order to isolate the problem, I also tried to reproduce it with my own class
hierarchy, independent of UIKit:

```
class BaseClass : NSObject {
    var parentViewController : BaseClass?
}

class FirstSubClass : BaseClass { }

class SecondSubClass : BaseClass { }

extension BaseClass {

    func traverseAndFindClass<T where T : BaseClass>(T.Type) -> T? {
        var currentVC = self
        while let parentVC = currentVC.parentViewController {
            println("comparing \(parentVC) to \(T.description())")
            if let result = parentVC as? T { // (XXX)
                return result
            }
            currentVC = parentVC
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let base = BaseClass()
base.parentViewController = FirstSubClass()

if let result = base.traverseAndFindClass(SecondSubClass.self) {
    println("found: \(result)")
} else {
    println("not found")
}
```

And guess what? Now it works as expected! The output is

```
comparing <MyApp.FirstSubClass: 0x7fff38f78c40> to MyApp.SecondSubClass
not found
```

---

**UPDATE:**

- Removing the type constraint in the generic method

  ```
  func traverseAndFindClass<T>(T.Type) -> T?
  ```

  as suggested by @POB in a comment makes it work as expected.
- Replacing the optional binding by a "two-step binding"

  ```
  if let result = parentVC as Any as? T { // (XXX)
  ```

  as suggested by @vacawama in his answer also makes it work as expected.
- Changing the build configuration from "Debug" to "Release" also makes the
  method work as expected. (I have tested this only in the iOS Simulator so far.)

The last point could indicate that this is a Swift compiler or runtime bug. And I still
cannot see why the problem occurs with subclasses of `UIViewController`, but not
with subclasses of my `BaseClass`. Therefore I will keep the question open for a
while before accepting an answer.

---

**UPDATE 2:** This has been fixed as of **Xcode 7**.

With the final Xcode 7
release the problem does not occur anymore. The optional binding
`if let result = parentVC as? T` in the `traverseAndFindClass()` method
now works (and fails) as expected, both in Release and Debug configuration.

Comment: If you try `func traverseAndFindClass<T>(T.Type) -> T? {/*...*/}` instead of `func traverseAndFindClass<T where T : UIViewController>(T.Type) -> T? {/*...*/}`, it will print "Not found" for `if let vc = self.traverseAndFindClass(UICollectionViewController.self)`. However, `if let vc = self.traverseAndFindClass(UIViewController.self)` and `if let vc = self.traverseAndFindClass(UINavigationController.self)` will both print "Found: <vc>".

Comment: @POB: That does indeed work (as does the solution suggested in vacawama's answer), but I still fail to understand *why*.

Comment: Could be something obscure, have you tried asking on dev forums?

Comment: @nkukushkin: "Cross-posted" at https://devforums.apple.com/thread/245561.

Comment: Re: In order to isolate the problem. To replicate, the code in the extension should be func traverseAndFindClass<T where T : **NSObject**>(T.Type) -> T? {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to conditionally cast an object of type `UINavigationController` to a `UICollectionViewController` in a Playground:

```
var nc = UINavigationController()

if let vc = nc as? UICollectionViewController {
    println("Yes")
} else {
    println("No")
}
```

You get this error:

**Playground execution failed: :33:16: error: 'UICollectionViewController' is not a subtype of 'UINavigationController'
if let vc = nc as? UICollectionViewController {**

but if instead you do:

```
var nc = UINavigationController()

if let vc = (nc as Any) as? UICollectionViewController {
    println("Yes")
} else {
    println("No")
}
```

it prints "No".

So I suggest trying:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func traverseAndFindClass<T where T : UIViewController>(T.Type) -> T? {
        var currentVC = self
        while let parentVC = currentVC.parentViewController {
            println("comparing \(parentVC) to \(T.description())")
            if let result = (parentVC as Any) as? T { // (XXX)
                return result
            }
            currentVC = parentVC
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: That does indeed work as expected (as does the solution suggested by @POB in a comment), but I still fail to understand *why*. And where is the difference to my second BaseClass/FirstSubClass/SecondSubClass example? Btw. `if let result = (parentVC as AnyObject) as? T` does *not* work.

Comment: The same problem still occurs with the latest Xcode 6.3.1, and you workaround also still works. Seems that there is no better solution!