# self.dynamicType not work for Generic type in Swift?

Tags: generics, inheritance, swift

I tried to use Generic type in Swift, but I found that it is not working well with inheritance and override. Here is an code example:

```
class A {
    class var test: String{
        return getName()
    }
    class func getName() -> String {
        return "I'm class A"
    }
    func doSomething() -> Void {
        println(self.dynamicType.test)
    }
}
class B : A {
    override class func getName() -> String {
        return "I'm class B"
    }
}
class C<T: A> {
    func doSomething() -> Void {
        var x = T()
        x.doSomething()
    }
}
var c = C<B>()
c.doSomething()//This line prints out "I'm class A"
```

Looks like even I specified the type as class B when creating the instance of class C, the new instance created with Generic type T still in type class A.

There is an similar question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899744/wrong-generic-type-in-swift
But no answer/solution yet, is this a bug of Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift generics not preserving type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280176/swift-generics-not-preserving-type)

Comment: You are correct Rintaro, I used the work around listed in that post and it works.